# Sum the two numbers

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

**If you know that:**

> TWO + THREE = TILAS
>   THREE + NINE = TUZRI
>   FOUR + TWO = GIRF
>   EIGHT + NINE = EVOUX
>   NINE + NINE = BARAI

**Can you tell:**

> **TWO + NINE = ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> OCJS - Interpret each word as a number in base 26, with A=0, B=1, etc. Then use normal addition (be sure to carry 26's when necessary)!